# Where can I find the source code for built in dialogs (WelcomeDlg, ErrorDlg, etc)?

Tags: wix, wix3

I've built an installer based on `WixUI_FeatureTree.wxs`.  I now need to add a third page with some additional controls.  I would like it to look the same as `CustomizeDlg` in `WixUI_FeatureTree.wxs`. Where can I look to find where it's created/defined.

I understand there may not be a WXS file for it, but I still wanted to look at where it's created/defined so I can build an identical dialog using all the same properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For WiX Toolset v3, you want the [UIExtension](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib).This is [WixUI_FeatureTree](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/WixUI_FeatureTree.wxs).

Comment: github.com giveth!